# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../

Tags: node.js, user-interface, npm, sap-commerce-cloud

i am new for nodejs, in my hybris project, first i installed nodejs, run 'npm install','npm i cross-env' commands, when i run the command 'npm run hybris' from node_module folder, i got some errors can you provide any solution.

```
C:\Atlas_Insta\hybris\bin\custom\rodanandfields\rodanandfieldsstorefront\FE-Develop>npm run hybris

> RodanAndFields@1.0.0 hybris C:\Atlas_Insta\hybris\bin\custom\rodanandfields\rodanandfieldsstorefront\FE-Develop
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production gulp hybris-build

[15:29:07] Using gulpfile C:\Atlas_Insta\hybris\bin\custom\rodanandfields\rodanandfieldsstorefront\FE-Develop\gulpfile.js
[15:29:07] Starting 'clean'...
[15:29:07] Finished 'clean' after 128 ms
[15:29:07] Starting 'markupCompile'...
[15:29:08] Starting 'sass'...
[15:29:09] Finished 'sass' after 615 ms
[15:29:09] Starting 'js'...
[15:29:09] Finished 'js' after 129 ms
[15:29:09] Starting 'copy-img'...
[15:29:09] Finished 'copy-img' after 584 μs
[15:29:09] Starting 'copy-fonts'...
[15:29:09] Finished 'copy-fonts' after 597 μs
[15:29:09] Starting 'copy-api'...
[15:29:09] Finished 'copy-api' after 630 μs
[15:29:09] Starting 'read-templates'...
[15:29:09] Finished 'read-templates' after 1.87 ms
All templates written successfully!
[15:29:32] Version: webpack 1.15.0
  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
 app.js  1.19 MB       0  [emitted]  app
app.map  9.63 MB       0  [emitted]  app

ERROR in C:/Atlas_Repo/bin/custom/rodanandfields/rodanandfieldsstorefront/FE-Develop/web/webroot/WEB-INF/r2/fe-components/checkout/order-summary/order-summary.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../../../_ui/frontend/js/analytics/analytics-eventmap-r2 in C:\Atlas_Repo\bin\custom\rodanandfields\rodanandfieldsstorefront\FE-Develop\web/webroot/WEB-INF/r2/fe-components\checkout\order-summary
 @ C:/Atlas_Repo/bin/custom/rodanandfields/rodanandfieldsstorefront/FE-Develop/web/webroot/WEB-INF/r2/fe-components/checkout/order-summary/order-summary.js 23:30-103

ERROR in C:/Atlas_Repo/bin/custom/rodanandfields/rodanandfieldsstorefront/FE-Develop/web/webroot/WEB-INF/r2/fe-components/checkout/checkout-form-billing/checkout-form-billing.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../../../_ui/frontend/js/analytics/analytics-config-r2 in C:\Atlas_Repo\bin\custom\rodanandfields\rodanandfieldsstorefront\FE-Develop\web/webroot/WEB-INF/r2/fe-components\checkout\checkout-form-billing
 @ C:/Atlas_Repo/bin/custom/rodanandfields/rodanandfieldsstorefront/FE-Develop/web/webroot/WEB-INF/r2/fe-components/checkout/checkout-form-billing/checkout-form-billing.js 23:22-93
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Hybris version are you using? I had a smilar problem with hybris 6.6. It worked for me after I switch to node v6.14.3 I was using a more recent node with a more recent npm version.

I found this version inside the npmancillary extension's folder

ext-content/npmancillary/resources/npm/node